# How to use the same virtual memory block each time program is run in C#

Tags: c#, memory, dll, memory-address

I have a program written in C# which uses an external DLL. I am on Windows 7 64bit. This DLL requires a contiguous block of 160MB in memory. Basically, I call a function in this DLL and it does work for a long time while invoking a callback function I pass to it. One of the arguments to the DLL function that begins this process is an integer memory address that the process will attempt to use. The DLL takes care of memory allocation, it just needs 160MB memory free, and you can choose to pass in the starting address of this memory block (or 0 if you want the library to find it itself).

If I pass 0 as the parameter, it works fine as the library is able to find memory itself. But to exploit certain features of this library, I need to be able to pass this DLL the same memory address each time I start a new process (and multiple identical processes may be run in parallel).

Given Windows programs have their own virtual address space, how can I be sure that this library will be able to use the same 160MB block of virtual memory in all processes? Even though application I have written has a deterministic startup process, I have found that using one specific memory address (eg 0xABC00000) may work a few times but then fail on the third as the DLL cannot allocate memory there as it's already been used.

Sorry for the long question, and I hope this makes it clear what I am trying to do. I just don't know how to go about ensuring an identically addressed block of memory is available to an external DLL in C# between multiple runs of the same process. Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear why you need a specific address. Things happen that can make a specific address not available. Why can't you allocate 160MB and use whatever address you get?

Comment: @user3344003 It's to use certain features of the API. One feature is the ability to save the current state of the DLL process, and to be able to restore that state in subsequent (or parallel) processes. This state file the DLL produces requires that all processes that load it use the same base memory address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I never came back to answer this question after I figured it out. It turns out it's rather simple using the ***VirtualAlloc*** function from **kernel32.dll**.

In my case, I needed to reserve the same virtual address for an external process each time the program was opened (or in each process if multiple copies were running at the same time). So what I did was basically choose a virtual address and hard-code that into the program. This way, the external process would always be able to use the same virtual-address block of memory:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, UIntPtr dwSize, AllocationType lAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);

// use same virtual address in all processes
const uint reserveAddress = 0x00CF0000;

// reserve 160MB at that address immediately at the start of the program
VirtualAlloc(new IntPtr(reserveAddress), new UIntPtr(160*1024*1024), AllocationType.RESERVE, MemoryProtection.EXECUTE_READWRITE);

// now just pass that same address to my external process when needed
int result = StartExternalProcess(reserveAddress);
```

This worked for me and the external process was able to reload it's saved state at the same memory location each time the program was started. It's an unusual requirement to be sure, but it was a requirement of the third-party library I was using. I hope this helps others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me review the concept of virtual address spaces.

Each address space has access to virtual addresses, for example, let's talk about virtual addresses 0x001000 to 0x24000.

Address space 1 has these addresses as well as address space 2, etc.  However, the actual physical storage for address space1 might be 0x091000 to 0x2D0000 while the same virtual addresses for address space 2 are mapped to physical addresses 0x011000 to 0x25000.

So far, in this description, it is NOT possible for two address spaces to share the same physical storage.  However, each address space has access to "global" addresses that are physically the same for each address space.

So, browse MSDN (Microsoft developers network) and scan for "atom" and/or "global addresses" and the like.  You should be able to find the Microsoft calls that allow you to allocate global storage which is available to other processes.  If you can't find this info. on MSDN, ping me back and I will do a search.

Comment: I'm not after sharing the same global address/physical memory between processes. In my case, each DLL will have its own unique physical storage. I just need to make sure that the virtual address space used by each and every process that loads this DLL for this process is the same even though each process is in a different part of memory with its own unique block of memory. So each process will use virtual address 0x124000 but have its own unique block of memory. It's the virtual address that needs to be the same.

Comment: Why do you have this requirement?  On the surface, it appears to serve no purpose.